# Where is an example of "foreign airspace designated in the United States" mentioned in 91.129?

Tags: faa-regulations, far-91, part-91-operations

Reading 91.129 regarding Class D ops and establishing communications, (c)(1) mentions:
"including foreign ATC in the case of foreign airspace designated in the United States"

Can anyone point to an example of such airspace?

Ref.: https://www.gleim.com/aviation/faraim/index.php?leafNum=91.129

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [Sault Ste. Marie Airport (CYAM)](https://www.aopa.org/destinations/airports/CYAM/details) is a Canadian airport with Class D airspace that extends into US territory:

> [image: Screenshot from Skyvector of a portion of the Lake Huron VFR sectional chart, depicting the Class D control zone around Sault Ste Marie airport (a portion of which covers US territory)]
> <sup>[Skyvector](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46.48506133796364,-84.50958251360171&chart=301&zoom=1)</sup>

Comment: The chart there shows the atc boundary running through the class D. Do you know how that is managed?

Comment: @TomMcW I would assume that the tower would be able to take handoffs from both ARTCC/ACC facilities, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @TomMcW also possible: the airspace boundaries have different altitude restrictions, which would also deconflict.